# Why "Go get it" for Research Assistant badge leading to favorite tags list?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, tag-watching, badge-progress

Clicking on the "Go get it" button for Research Assistant (seepicture below) redirects me to the page that **[Manages Favorite/Ignored tags](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/4281779#interesting-tags)**.

> [image]

Shouldn't it link me to the **[New tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new)** instead?

This is only when I have a favorite tag. If I don't, I will lead straight to the [Tags](//stackoverflow.com/tags) page.

What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Interesting as when I did this, it lead me straight to the list of tags rather than the management of favorite and ignored tags

Comment: @PythonMaster that's because you don't have any favorite tags. If you'll add even one, the link will be to what OP said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall the reasoning there correctly... the idea here is that you'd be more likely to be able to edit tag wikis for tags you're comfortable with or interested in. This correlates highly with tags you marked as favorite, hence the redirect to that page. (Note that each tag there *is* a link to the actual tag pages.)